# Weird Powershell Console output for GetAssemblyName.FullName

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, .net-assembly

I tried this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/11/05/quick-tip-find-the-four-part-name-for-an-assembly.aspx

Why do I get this`畁湳桡敭戠楥⁭畁牦晵湥瘠湯∠敇䅴獳浥汢乹浡≥洠瑩ㄠ䄠杲浵湥⡴湥㨩†䐢牥倠慦⁤਍慨⁴楥⁮湵腧瑬杩獥䘠牯慭⹴ഢ䤊⁮敚汩㩥‱敚捩敨㩮റ⬊嬠祓瑳浥刮晥敬瑣潩⹮獁敳扭祬慎敭㩝䜺瑥獁敳扭祬慎敭∨⤢䘮汵乬浡൥⬊縠繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾繾ൾ †⬠䌠瑡来牯䥹普⁯††††㨠丠瑯灓捥晩敩㩤⠠⤺嬠ⱝ䴠瑥潨䥤癮捯瑡潩䕮捸灥楴湯਍††‫畆汬兹慵楬楦摥牅潲䥲⁤›牁畧敭瑮硅散瑰潩൮ ਍`

Is there another easy way to find out the full name of an assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exception message in German that was encoded in the `EUC-JP` encoding, and then the byte stream was interpreted as UTF-16.

It reads:

```
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "GetAssemblyName" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Der Pfad
hat ein ung?ltiges Format."
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ [System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName("").FullName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

Try fixing your default encodings to be UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks - even thogh this means I do not get the desired information out of it. ~.~

Comment: @0rube It would suggest you are not passing correct dll path to the script. `$(TargetPath)` is a Visual Studio macro, what value does it have for you?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would have helped to just clear the `Treat output as Unicode` Checkbox in the `External Tools` Wizard. Stupid me! ^^